# How to rotate Title Label of Segmented Control with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol, segmentedcontrol

I rotated a Segmented Control in swift, in order to have a vertical Control. but I wanna rotate the Title Label in 90 degrees

[image]

With this code, I can change Title text and color (in Red) as well, but I can't rotate Label, I don't know why.

```
for view in cell.mySegmentedControl.subviews {
            for subview in view.subviews {
                if subview is UILabel {
                    let sub = subview as! UILabel
                    sub.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/4)
                    sub.textColor = UIColor.red
                    sub.text = "OO"
                }
            }
        }
```

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: It doesn't work, actually I added the two 00's because I wanted to see that I could change that label and color, but if I remove it, still doesn't work, doesn't rotate

Comment: Why dont you rotate the whole segmentControl..??

Comment: I rotated the whole segmentControl, that's why the Text is rotated, I wanna rotate the label title again in order to display it horizontally

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the default behavior of the UISegment Color.

What I would recommend is creating a custom Segmented view using Vertical Stack View! Add the labels to the Stack View and customize them. This would be easier and more convenient